# Script/Rotina para executar programa

Tags: windows, script, vbs

Ola.

Eu gostaria de um exemplo de Script pelo VBS mesmo, para que verifique se há atividade no Windows e para que se não houver atividade nos 15 minutos anteriores, esse script executa um determinado programa.

Comment: defina "atividade" - o seu script estar rodando já é uma atividade!

Comment: atividade no windows, tipo movimentação do mouse, ou digitação no teclado, tipo isso

Answer (score 1):

Testado no powershell 5.1, windows 10.

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke.Win32 {

    public static class UserInput {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
            public uint cbSize;
            public int dwTime;
        }

        public static DateTime LastInput {
            get {
                DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
                DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
                return lastInput;
            }
        }

        public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
            get {
                return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(LastInput);
            }
        }

        public static int LastInputTicks {
            get {
                LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
                lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
                GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
                return lii.dwTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
'@
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
For ( $i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++ ) {
    Write-Host -Object 'Última entrada', ( [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::LastInput ).ToString( 'T' )
    Write-Host -Object 'Ociosidade atual', ( [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime ).ToString( 'T' )
    Start-Sleep -Seconds ( Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5 )
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845508/get-idle-time-of-machine

Talvez você não consiga testar os 15 minutos de forma exata, pois você teria que verificar a cada segundo e isso vai pesar no processamento da máquina.

Talvez um intervalo de 2 minutos para o comando "Start-Sleep" seria interessante. Basta testar o tempo de ociosidade. Se superior a 15 minutos, executa alguma rotina, usando o comando "Start-Process".